# MySQL Errors, Active Connection, Denied Access, No privileges

Tags: mysql, macos

```
mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();

| USER()          | CURRENT_USER() | apple@localhost | @localhost     |1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'apple'@'localhost';
```

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

```
--------------------
Connection:
Name: LOCAL
Host: localhost (UNIX socket)
Server: MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Version: 5.6.16
Login User: apple
Current User: @localhost
```

> An unhandled exception occurred (Error executing 'SELECT PROCESSLIST_ID,IF (NAME = 'thread/sql/event_scheduler','event_scheduler',PROCESSLIST_USER) PROCESSLIST_USER,PROCESSLIST_HOST,PROCESSLIST_DB,PROCESSLIST_COMMAND,PROCESSLIST_TIME,PROCESSLIST_STATE,THREAD_ID,TYPE,NAME,PARENT_THREAD_ID,INSTRUMENTED,PROCESSLIST_INFO FROM performance_schema.threads WHERE TYPE <> 'BACKGROUND''
>   SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'threads'.
>   SQL Error: 1142). Please refer to the log files for details.

I am unable to access any database functions, receiving denial errors whenever I attempt an action.  This is a brand new installation and I am new to MySQL, I have looked up other questions yet haven't found an example of everything being denied.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to login to mysql as root? 
You can do that by using this command in the terminal:

```
Shell> mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name
```

Comment: I have the same problem logging in with root and I haven't been able to create a database yet.

Comment: Perhaps it will solve the problem if you create a new super user.

Try to follow this guide: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html